# Google Tag Manager ecommerce transaction not firing

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm implementing Google Tag Manager and want to record the ecommerce ending amount on a custom ASP page.  This unfortunately has to be at the bottom of the page. After finding several solutions here and elsewhere I'm missing something, probably basic, as I just can't get it working. Enhanced ecommerce is enabled in Google Analytics, the GTM is correctly running GA on page load but not the transaction tag.  I even switched the GTM trigger from All Pages to DOM Ready after reading it would help with bottom page code but it didn't. What should I change?

**UPDATE:**

After trying a few other options I still can't get it working, here is a test page to look at and the attached images are updated.  Standard ecommerce is enabled.

https://westernregional.org/test.asp

[image]
[image]
[image]
**UPDATE 2:**

Switched GTM trigger to "DOM Ready" and changed GA to "enhanced ecommerce"
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You mention "Enhanced ecommerce", but that dataLayer you are using is for standard ecommerce only. Also the "Transaction" tag is also specific to standard ecommerce. Can you clarify if you are indeed looking to use the EE reports? if so, then you will need to follow the correct EE payload, as specified in these docs: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

Comment: I had standard on originally, but read elsewhere that enabling enhanced wouldn't effect trying the standard code.  Is that incorrect?  I'm not sure anymore.  I just switched enhanced off, reloaded the page, but am still seeing that tag is not firing.

Comment: If you plan on using standard ecommerce (ie. the "Transaction" type tag), then don't mix it with Enhanced Ecommerce. This doesn't mean the two don't work together, but you sure are going to confuse yourself and others if you do so. Another thing is in your Trigger, you have the rule that Page URL equals stage9.asp AND stage10.asp. It says clearly that the tag fires if ALL the conditions are true, so double check that at least.

Comment: @nyuen I didn't even notice that they were AND operators as I need it to fire on either of the two pages.  I changed it to an OR, published the GTM changes, hard reloaded the stage9 page a few times but it's still not firing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use Events instead for Enhanced ecommerce tracking . I myself implemented enhanced ecommerce tracking many times using events and it worked .

Also I looked at the dataLayer and looks like you are not passing all the values required . Here is the link for implementing Enhanced ecommerce transaction event

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-content-enhanced-ecommerce/

Comment: I originally had Enhanced on but then switched and am trying to get the Standard ecommerce working as a start.  Enhanced is off in Analytics. 
 Anything you see on the demo page which would cause problems?  This thing is driving me crazy.

Comment: I understand you are trying to start with standard ecommerce tracking . I looked at your dataLayer, its looks just fine. Firstly did you see that the dataLayer variables are getting passed through GTM using preview mode ? Also make sure the dataLayer events are loaded before the GTM container code loads on the page. Lastly you said enhanced ecommerce is off in analytics, I didn't quite understand  , I implement enhanced ecommerce almost daily on many commerce websites and it works just fine for me

Comment: I assumed it would be easier to get Standard running then Enhanced since it had less required fields. "...dataLayer events are loaded before the GTM container code loads on the page" - how do i control which loads first?  On the page is only the GTM.

Comment: Added the "Data Layer" screenshot above from the preview mode

Comment: I see the dataLayer events working fine , Can you please try using events instead of transaction . set ecommerce equal to true in more settings , then check use datalayer option and in trigger fire it on Dom ready of the purchase tag

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, switched GA to enhanced, but it still doesn't seem to be collecting.  Included "update 2" above which new screenshots.

Comment: did you check if the data is showing up in GA ? if the the dataLayer is working then the values should show up in GA reports

Comment: The GA ecommerce report shows all zeros.  I ended preview mode for GTM and refreshed the page a few times but nothing shows in GA.  I don't think it will even after time if the tag is not firing on the page.  I seem to be stuck.

Comment: It's a few days later and nothing has shown in the GA ecommerce reports.  I wasn't sure if there was a day or two delay.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the dataLayer event seems not uploaded to google server. Try to add `event` property by GTM or by code, transaction data should be upload automatically.

You can use the `Google analytic Debuger` from chrome store.

[image: add event property]

Add event property

[image: Should be able to see some data with <code>ec:</code> initial after added the property]

Should be able to see some data with `ec:` initial after added the property